# Brain Testing Logical Reasoning Puzzle

Tags: riddle, mathematics, logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

[image: Can you answer this logical puzzle?]

Can you answer this logical puzzle?
Puzzle Source: https://www.funwithpuzzles.com/2018/12/brain-testing-logical-reasoning-puzzle.html

Answer (score 5):

Answer:

> Jupiter = 578

Explanation:

> The first digit is the position from the Sun (Mercury = 1, Venus = 2, etc.) so Jupiter = 5.
>  The second digit is the length of the planet's name, so Jupiter = 7.
>  To get the third digit, multiply the first and the second modulo 9; e.g. Venus $2 \times 5 = 10 \equiv 1 \pmod 9$. Therefore, Jupiter is $5 \times 7 = 35 \equiv 8 \pmod 9$.

Also,

> THAN is misspelled, it should be THEN.

Answer (score 1):

> Mercury=177 
>  First number from left is planets position from the Sun so mercury is the first planet from the sun, hence number 1. 
>  Second number that is number 7 is total number of alphabets present in the word Mercury.
> The third number is the multiplication of first and the second i.e 1x7 if the resultent number is of two digits then we have to add those two digits with each other but if the result is a single digit then that single digit itself is the third number.
> Similarly for Venus=251 
>  i.e Venus second planet -->2 
>  No of letters in Venus -->5 
>  Multiplication of 2x5=10  
>  Adding the two digits of 10 --> 1+0=1 
>  Hence 251.. ✓✓✓✓ 
> So for Jupiter
>  Jupiter is 5th planet from the Sun✓✓✓--> 5 
>  Jupiter word has 7 letters so ✓✓------------> 7 
>  Third digit from left5x7= 35 --> 3+5=8✓✓ 
>  So answer is "Jupiter= 578"✓✓✓✓✓✓

Comment: Hi Anuroop, welcome to SE Puzzling! As to not spoil the answer for other people coming into this puzzle, I ask you to start hiding your answer with spoilers marks (just put >! before your answer, or read more on the formatting help page). Also, remember to check previous answers so there aren't duplicates :) Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

The first digit gives the position of the planet from the Sun say it as A
The second digit is the number of letters on the left side of the equation say it as B
To get the third digit, multiply the first and second digit and add the digits of this result obtained. e.g 5x7 = 35 => 3+5 = 8

Comment: This is the same as Glorfindel's answer from over a year ago. Please check the existing answers before posting to ensure you're not posting a duplicate answer.